# ReactJS: Using value from form - radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I have a form with some variables:

```
  const [formModel, setFormModel] = useState({
    realm: '',
    deletedDate: 'all',
  });
```

the deletedDate is a radio button that should have as value -> "all", "true", "false"

the form is:

```
<AvForm model={formModel} onSubmit={filterResults} onReset={handleFormReset}>
 <AvGroup>
                    <Label id="realm" for="realm-realm">
                      Realm Name
                    </Label>
                    <AvField
                      id="realm"
                      data-cy="realm"
                      type="text"
                      name="realm"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      value={formModel.realm}
                    />
                  </AvGroup>
<FormGroup check>
                      <Label id="deletedDate" check>
                        <Input
                          id="deletedDate"
                          data-cy="deletedDate"
                          type="radio"
                          name="deletedDate"
                          value="all"
                          checked={formModel.deletedDate === 'all'}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />{' '}
                        All
                      </Label>
                      <br></br>
                      <Label id="deletedDate" check>
                        <Input
                          id="deletedDate"
                          data-cy="deletedDate"
                          type="radio"
                          name="deletedDate"
                          value="true"
                          checked={formModel.deletedDate === 'true'}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />{' '}
                        Yes
                      </Label>
                    </FormGroup>
                    <FormGroup check>
                      <Label id="deletedDate" check>
                        <Input
                          id="deletedDate"
                          data-cy="deletedDate"
                          type="radio"
                          name="deletedDate"
                          value="false"
                          checked={formModel.deletedDate === 'false'}
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />{' '}
                        No
                      </Label>
                    </FormGroup>
```

now when I submit the form I call the filterResults:

```
const handleChange = e => {
    console.log('e ', e);
    console.log('deletedDate ', formModel.deletedDate);
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log('name ', name, ' value ', value);
    setFormModel(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
    console.log('deletedDate ', formModel.deletedDate);
  };

  const filterResults = (event, errors, values) => {
    console.log('values ', values, 'event ', event, ' errors ', errors);
    let entity = null;
    if (errors.length === 0) {
      entity = {
        ...values,
      };
    }
    console.log('entity is ', entity);
    if (entity) {
```

Now My problem is:

In the filterResults I have inserted a console log to see the values.. when I submit the form I can read only the value about the realm and nothing about the deletedDate and I don't understand why. How can I do to use in the filterResult the deletedDate??
What is wrong with my form? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are using two different form which when you submit while using the props of the AV form you dont have access to other form values, i would recommend to store these values in the same form

```
 <AvForm model={formModel} onSubmit={filterResults} onReset={handleFormReset}>
 <AvGroup>
                    <Label id="realm" for="realm-realm">
                      Realm Name
                    </Label>
                    <AvField
                      id="realm"
                      data-cy="realm"
                      type="text"
                      name="realm"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      value={formModel.realm}
                    />
                  </AvGroup>
<AvGroup>
                    <Label id="realm" for="realm-realm">
                      Radio Input
                    </Label>
                    <AvField
                      id="deletedDate"
                      data-cy="deletedDate"
                      type="type value this for uses for radio inputs"
                      name="deletedDate"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      value={formModel.deletedDate}
                    />
                  </AvGroup>
```

, but if you want to make this work, I would suggest get your values from the state, here you are storing your values in the state but not doing anything with them

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in the type I should insert "radio" to have a radio button? and the value of the radio button where should goes?

Comment: im not sure for this form library, you should check the documentation and look for the usage of the radio button, but important thing is the keep all the fileds inside <AvForm /> tag so you would have access, EDIT: found the docs and examples here https://availity.github.io/availity-reactstrap-validation/components/avform/